# Is to possible to Map two Array in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have below two attributes `start` and `end` and I want to split flow file on the basis of array data.

For example,

**Attributes are:**

```
start = ["ABC", "BCD", "XYZ"]
end =  ["123", "234", "567"]
```

these two attributes will be part of a single flow file.

Next I want split this flow file into three flow file as below:

**flowfile1** `ABC,123`

**flowfile2** `BCD,234`

**flowfile3** `XYZ,567`

**Note:** The length and type of both Arrays `start` and `end` will be same

Please help me to achieve this using NiFi only. **I do not want to use any scripting language with NiFi.**

Comment: imho, better to use script

Comment: put each attribute into a separate file content -> SplitJson -> merge content for each pair of files